# Understanding google spreadsheets set vs get logic

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm desperately trying to learn to "think" in this language (my native coding language is VBA/ASP).

Here is a very basic example that simply reads the contents of a specific cell in Sheet1 and then assigns that value to a variable named rngVal

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"));
var rngVal = ss.setActiveSelection("A1").getValues();
```

When I attempt to deconstruct this very simple 3-line piece of code (in the interest of understanding it's purpose), I admit to being rather perplexed.

Here's why:

When I insert a msgbox after each line, I get this:

`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` = "**Spreadsheet**"

`ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"));` = "**Spreadsheet**"

`var rngVal = ss.setActiveSelection("A1").getValues();` = **The cell value**

What is "**Spreadsheet**"?
How is this helpful(?) and how can I use it for the benefit of navigating the worksheet and reading/writing values within it?
That's 2 lines of code that does what(?), and for what benefit?

(I'm not trying to be combative, I'm just trying to understand so that I can learn to "think" in this language)

Secondly:
In the first line, what am I **get** ting?

In the second line I'm first **set** 'ting, and then I'm **get** 'ting? (I'm very confused about what that line is actually doing)

In the third (last) line there is more **set** 'ting and **get** 'ting, although this time it's not nested.

This is very basic code (functionally), but I'm having trouble grasping it's logic in terms of how to "think" using that logic.

Is there anyone out there who would be kind enough to show some patience and help me by describing the step by step logic of this simple code of selecting a cell, capturing it's value, and then assigning it to a variable?
Please understand, that when I "think" of how to do that very simple task, I can do it in one very concise line (in VBA)...

```
rngVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

...therefore I am *really* confused by all of the "Spreadsheet" stuff and the need for 3 lines filled with **set**'s and **get**'s.

Anyone? *Please?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google uses Javascript Classes to represent these different Objects.
I've split line 3 into two parts to help with my explanation. Please compare:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"));
var rng = ss.setActiveSelection("A1");
var val = rng.getValues();
```

Each line above returns a different class of Object. The first line returns an Object with class Spreadsheet, the second line returns an object of class Sheet, the third line returns an object of class Range, and the final line returns an object of class Object.

Take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) for documentation on the various actions (methods) that can be performed on/with the different classes of objects. When I'm building a Google App, I live on that webpage.

To compare the above with the code you understand from VBA, this line:

```
rngVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

Could be written in Javascript in one line as follows:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").setActiveSelection("A1").getValues();
```

Hope that helps. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: THIS... " var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").setActiveSelection("A1").getValues();" IS BEAUTIFUL! I appreciate this so much! Just one more question: The Spreadsheet is GET. The Sheet is GET. Yet the Range is SET, and then the Value of that range is GET (again). What is the concept of SET and GET in this particular piece of code? Btw, how is it that I never see code written in that way? It's so much more elegant and straightforward than what I always come across (and more importantly, IT WORKS!).

Comment: Never mind Matt. You already answered that. Class and Object. Thanks again!!! (also for the link!)

Comment: Glad to help! Hope you build something awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm somehow the correct answer (my other one) got voted down. Again its pointless to do setactiveselection, there is no need to change the selected cell it just makes your code slower.

Comment: I have no idea how this site works regarding "voting". I'm likely to grasp JS before I'll ever figure out the non-intuitive voting system here, but feel free to instruct me on it and I'll correct the apparent injustice. I'm grateful, so "green check-marks" for anyone and everyone who helps me. So.... how do I do that? And FYI: Apparently I lack sufficient "reputation" to be thankful. Uh... ok. Whatever that means.

Comment: You're right... and the accepted answer is not really true:  get values with an S will return an unnecessary and unwanted matrix instead of a single value... I up voted to try to compensate :-)

Comment: NICE! Well played, Serge insas! Way to take care of the those who take the time to help others :)  And btw, very true regarding Value and ValueS. I figured that out as I further developed my script. And feel free to insert your input (and editing abilities) on all of my future questions :P You seem to be on top of everything here! Thanks!

Comment: thanks. btw the comment was mainly addressed to Zig Mandel (I just forgot to mention it ;-) but I appreciate your compliment of course :).

Answer (score 0):

You guys are doing it  more complex than neeeded. No need to mess with selection.
Getactivespreadsheet ().getsheetbyname ("x").getrange ("a1").getValue () also works.

Comment: Nice! You guys have allowed me to learn exactly what I hoped to understand. I am highly appreciative. Thank you for sharing the knowledge!